# Running a script after startx automatically

Tags: linux, bash, sh, raspberry-pi

With my Raspberry Pi, I managed to login pi user automatically, then start tomcat automatically and then start X server as well.

For those interested,
auto login:

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

instead of

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1
```

in /etc/inittab

and

```
sh /home/pi/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/startup.sh
su -l pi -c startx
exit 0
```

in /etc/rc.local

Now, I'd like to launch a java program (jar file) that I made, automatically after server X has started. How could I do that?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**
On my Rapsberry, as LXDE is used, http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

startx uses the ~HOME/.xinitrc file to load programs at the startup of X
 where ~HOME is the home directory of the user running X [ in this case pi]

see http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/startx.1.html for an example of .xinitrc

Comment: Thanks, it's working.. partially. As the .xinitrc file was not existing, I created it using
`echo "jar -jar myfile.jar" > .xinitrc`
After a reboot, the jar file is correctly launched but all the rest of the screen remains black (cannot see wallpaper, bottom bar, icons, etc). I think the file is overriding something. How to fix it ? Thanks