# Running my application after all boot up process

Tags: linux, bash, embedded, sh

i want to run  my application on board(i.MX233 EVK) after all modules loaded.i want to add auto log-in.i got this link but the procedure not working.

[Running a script after startx automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916921/running-a-script-after-startx-automatically)

where can i add small script to load my application(C language) automatically after boot-up of board.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been literally answered million times on Internet. Please have a look at [How to run a shell script at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Put your script in /etc/init.d/rcS or rc file init process will automatically execute it.

```
/etc/init.d/rcS
your_script.sh &
```