# Boot raspbian to start Xserver and WPF automatically

Tags: linux, mono, debian, gtk#, raspbian

I have a C# GTK# app that plays video from a network stream.

What I need is step by step instructions for raspbian to:
1. auto start xserver after boot
2. auto load the app after xserver

If someone can provide me instructions I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!
Dan F

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916921/running-a-script-after-startx-automatically?

Comment: I did not see that one, thank you for linking it. I do have two questions:
1. in what is stated for rc.local, do I remove the portion for tomcat since I do not need to launch a java related web app or is there some need to launch tomact before xserver?
2. hes using a feature in lxde to launch the java app, what would be the processes in raspbian distro?

thank you!
Dan F